# Can't open nor install 2D Sprite Editor through package manager

Tags: unity

In unity `2019.2.10f1 Personal edition` on `Windows 10` I wish to edit a spritesheet through the built-in sprite editor.
When I click on the "Sprite Editor" button I get a popup that says

> No Sprite Editor Window registered. Please download 2D sprite package from Package Manager.

(Fig 0)

Attempting to follow these instructions I opened the package manager (fig 1) but couldn't find an install button for the "2D Sprite" package (fig 2).

I searched on the internet if there was any way to manually download it but couldn't find any matching package.

Is this a bug, why can I not install this package ?

[image: Sprite editor error message] (fig 0)

[image] (fig 1)

[image] (fig 2)

Comment: Hey, welcome here! Are you sure you don't have an install button on the very bottom right of the package manager window?

Comment: You, sir, are a genius. Or at least, not as dumb as I am ...
If you wish to you can add an answer so that I can upvote and accept it, i'll delete mine then.

Comment: No genius involved. I've just done that same mistake once and lost too many hours on it to be proud of anything related to it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a sneaky discrete button hidden on the bottom right of that editor window ;) you'll find it hidden there.